# How to resolve required bundle error in maven project for spring boot and batch project?

Tags: spring-boot, maven, maven-plugin, slf4j

I am getting the following error in my log while running a spring boot and spring batch project.

```
!SESSION 2023-01-19 14:16:57.128 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=unknown
java.version=17.0.5
java.vendor=Eclipse Adoptium
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_IN
Command-line arguments:  -data c:\Users\Vaishali\AppData\Roaming\Code\User\workspaceStorage\f4e97db7acc29bd26ac0402f02ff6092\redhat.java\jdt_ws

!ENTRY com.microsoft.java.maven.plugin 4 0 2023-01-19 14:16:59.321
!MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not resolve module: com.microsoft.java.maven.plugin [109]
  Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.slf4j.api

    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:463)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel$2.run(ModuleContainer.java:1852)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxContainerAdaptor$1$1.execute(EquinoxContainerAdaptor.java:136)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1845)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1786)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.doContainerStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1750)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1672)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:234)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:345)
```

I am unable to get the project to build.

Comment: Is there any chance you can self answer this now? I'm having the same problem